# How to transfer complex image URL to OG image in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

**Example image URL :** `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodbase-*****.appspot.com/o/images%2F1684594858456-f4.png?alt=media&token=*******-****-****-****-********`

**OG URL :** `http://localhost:3000/api/og2?img=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foodbase-*****.appspot.com/o/images%2F1684594858456-f4.png?alt=media&token=*******-****-****-****-********`

og2.js

```js
import { ImageResponse } from 'next/server';

export const runtime = 'edge';

export default async function GET(request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
  const imgUrl = searchParams.get('img');

  return new ImageResponse(
    (
      <div style={{
            display: 'flex',
            fontSize: 10,
            color: 'black',
            background: '#f6f6f6',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            paddingTop: 50,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'}}
        >
        <p>imgUrl: {img}</p>
      </div>
    ),
    {
      width: 1200,
      height: 630,
    },
  );
}
```

This code takes the OG URL and takes params out of it. I searched for `img`. In the result image as you can see it cuts some parts of it. The first cut part I noticed is "/o/images **%2F**" and the second part is after "media".
How can I solve this?

Generated OG Image:
[image]